# view a list of $rollout features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollout

I'm using [rollout](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rollout/2.5.0/Rollout) to set feature flags in a rails app. I often use the command `$rollout.active_features` to view what flags are active. Is there a command to display inactive features? Or all features that exist?

Comment: There is [`#features`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rollout/2.5.0/Rollout#features-instance_method) which seems to return the name of all features.

Comment: this was helpful, but it appears that there are more features that exist that aren't being returned by this command.... i wonder if there is something in my project hiding these. do you know if that's possible?